# How i declare a var in Laravel if i need the $row from a foreach in the blade view data

Tags: php, laravel

i made a code and now i want to export it in laravel.

in my initial code i've got this

```
while($row = $getRss->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $rss = simplexml_load_file($row["link"]);
 }
```

how can i now declare the `$rss` in my controller and pass it to my view?

Comment: Are you trying to create an xml? If yes you have a package for this https://github.com/orchestral/parser

Comment: Can you share your entire code? From where does `$getRss` come? Are you using some sort of library?

Comment: Create an array containing your RSS links (`$rssLinks`), then in you controller method return something like this: `return view('my-view-rss').with('rssLinks', $rssLinks);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to add your rss from controller to view

```
$arrRss = [];
while($row = $getRss->fetch_assoc()) {
     $rss = simplexml_load_file($row["link"]);
     array_push($arrRss,$rss);
 }

return view('the-blade-name',['rss' => $arrRss]);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to pass a variable in view(blade) file

```php
$rss = [];
```

```php
 return view('blade-file',['rss' => $rss]);
```

```php
 return view('blade-file')->with(['rss' => $rss]);
```

```php
 return view('blade-file',compact('rss'));
```

all of these gives you same result in view file